# Why Segmentation fault in gcc when malloc?

Tags: gcc, gdb, segmentation-fault, malloc

I wrote a piece of code to realize hash function. The problem comes when adding the 9th element "a12a" to the list, the gdb reports as below, and it seems the problem is happened during applying memory by malloc. But before adding this 9th element, I have ever successfully applied one time memory by malloc when adding the 6th element "ad", why the second time applying memory is failed?

```
Breakpoint 1, insert (p=0x3d2d10, value=0x4030e8 "a12a") at hashop.c:39
39              id = hash(value);
(gdb) n
40              *current = p + id;
(gdb)
41              if((*current)->value == NULL) {
(gdb)
44                      if((lookup(p+id, value)) == NULL) {
(gdb)
45                              new = (nList *)malloc(sizeof(nList));
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x7c938996 in ntdll!RtlDuplicateUnicodeString ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
(gdb)
```

And my code is:

```
void insert(nList *p, char *value)
{
    nList *new, **current;
    int id;

    id = hash(value);
    *current = p + id;
    if((*current)->value == NULL) {
        (*current)->value = value;
    } else {
        if((lookup(p+id, value)) == NULL) {
            new = (nList *)malloc(sizeof(nList));
            new->value = value;
            new->next = NULL;       
            while((*current)->next != NULL) {
                (*current) =(*current)->next;
            }
            (*current)->next = new;
        }
    }
}   

static char *str2[] = {"ac", "ba", "abv", "bc", "bx", "ad", "xx", "aaa", "a12a", "b123"};
```

And the hash id of each element is as below:

```
ac, HashId=6
ba, HashId=5
abv, HashId=3
bc, HashId=7
bx, HashId=8
ad, HashId=7
xx, HashId=0
aaa, HashId=1
a12a, HashId=3
b123, HashId=8
```

From above list, it is sure that the "bc" and "ad" has same hash id, so in my insert() function, I will apply a block of memory for storing "ad". And it is same for the "abv" and "a12a", I also applied a block of memory, but this time failed. Why? Anyone can figure out? Appreciated!

Comment: You should learn more about `gdb` in particular its `p`, `display`, `break`, `bt`, `watch` commands. And you don't tell us enough to get real help.

Comment: When you first initialize the list, do you set all `next`s to NULL? Maybe the pointer for `ad` just gets lucky.

Answer (score 4):

You're corrupting memory with this line:

```
*current = p + id;
```

Pass `-Wall` to gcc to turn on all warnings and you'll see:

```
buggy-hash.c: In function ‘insert’:
buggy-hash.c:19:14: warning: ‘current’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

TIP: Using `gcc -Wall` and running your program under a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) under Linux would make finding these memory problems a *lot* easier.

I'm guessing you're learning C programming by using CodeBlocks or some other IDE under Windows? Building your program in debug mode in Visual Studio would catch these problems as well.

Comment: Thanks scottt for pointing the -Wall parameter, and it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I have used p+id as the input of lookup function but forgot the p is already changed by *current. so the correct code is:

```
void insert(nList *p, char *value)
{
    nList *new, **current = &p;
    int id;
    id = hash(value);
    *current += id;

    if((*current)->value == NULL) {
        (*current)->value = value;
    } else {
        if((lookup(*current, value)) == NULL) {
            new = (nList *)malloc(sizeof(nList));

            if(new == NULL)
                printf("\nCannot get memory");
            else {
                new->value = value;
                new->next = NULL;       

                while((*current)->next != NULL) {
                    (*current) =(*current)->next;
                }

                (*current)->next = new;
            }
        }
    }
}
```